# Powershell script failing on Windows Server R12

Tags: powershell, window

I have this script:

```
$URI = "http://www.trlibor.org/fixingrates.asp"
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI

$1MRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")[11].InnerText
$1MRate = $1MRate.replace(',','.')
$1MRate

$2MRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")[15].InnerText
$2MRate= $2MRate.replace(',','.')
$2MRate

$3MRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")[19].InnerText
$3MRate= $3MRate.replace(',','.')
$3MRate


$6MRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")[23].InnerText
$6MRate= $6MRate.replace(',','.')
$6MRate

$9MRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")[27].InnerText
$9MRate= $9MRate.replace(',','.')
$9MRate

$1YRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")[31].InnerText
$1YRate= $1YRate.replace(',','.')
$1YRate
```

It's working TOTALLY fine on my machine, but when I run it on a Windows Server R12, the variables $1MRate...$2MRate are not getting values (null) as if the td elements do not exist on that page.

any idea why is that?

Comment: Access problems? check what is in `$HTML` (*"This site can’t be reached"*?)

Comment: I can reach it fine on my local machine, I can browse it fine on Server manually in IE.

Comment: I notice that on my local machine PS is 5 while on server it's 4

Comment: On the server side try `Write-Host $HTML.content` to confirm that this is what you expect (= the same on your local machine).

Comment: It turns out that the array [11] ...... don't work on PS4, is there another method to select the 11th td element other than [11]?

Comment: `$HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")` It is not an array but a Comobject, try convert it to an array by surrounding it into `@()`: `@($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td"))[11].InnerText` (I don't think it is a PowerShell difference but a .Net difference)

Answer (score 1):

IT TURNED OUT that $1MRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td")[11].InnerText  returns null in PS4!!

You have to use  $1MRate = $HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("td").item(11).InnerTex instead!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$HTML = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URI -ContentType "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

When upgrading from PowerShell 3 to 4, my `Invoke-WebRequest` broke and required `ContentType` to be explicitly stated.